# How to import photos from Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I noticed when I visit photo printing websites, they ask you if you would like to import your photos from Facebook. How do they do it? Does Facebook provide API to import users' photos?

I am mostly using PHP.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
   * get_albums()
   *
   * @param long $uid
   * @return array
   */
    function get_albums($uid=null)
    {
         if (empty($uid))
            $uid = $_REQUEST['fb_sig_user'];
        try
        {
            return $facebook->api_client->photos_getAlbums($uid,null);
        }
        catch (FacebookRestClientException $ex)     
        {
            return array();
        }
    }

/**
 * get_photos()
 *
 * @param bool $bool_pids
 * @param mixed $aids (array of album ids or null)
 * @return array
 */
 function get_photos($bool_pids=true, $aids=null, $pids=null)
 {
    try
    {
      $p = $facebook->api_client->photos_get(null, $aids, $pids);
    }
    catch (FacebookRestClientException $ex) { }

    if ($bool_pids)
    {
            $pids = array();
            if (!empty($p))
            foreach($p as $p0)
                    $pids[] = $p0['pid'];
            return $pids;
    }
    else
            return $p;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

get_albums returns an array of albums, do a var_dump to see what it returns.

```
$albums = get_albums($facebook);
foreach($albums as $album)
{
     if($album["count"] > 0)
     {
          //if the album has pictures, then do something with the album
     }
}

function get_albums($facebook)
{
    $fb_user = getFbUser($facebook);
    $myalbums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
    return $myalbums["data"];
}

function getFbUser($facebook)
{
    $fb_user = $facebook->getUser(); //gets user id

    if(is_null($fb_user))
    {
            header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos'))}");
            exit;
    }
    return $fb_user;
}

function getFb()
{
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'your_appid',
        'secret' => 'your_secret',
        'cookie' => true,
        ));
    return $facebook;
}
```

See: http://www.joeyrivera.com/2010/facebook-graph-api-app-easy-w-php-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can retrieve photos from users that have added you application and agreed to share such information. First you retrieve the albums using the photos_getAlbums API call, then you can loop over album ids and call photos_get to retrieve photos for the albums.

`/**
   * get_albums()
   *
   * @param long $uid
   * @return array
   */
    function get_albums($uid=null)
    {
         if (empty($uid))
            $uid = $_REQUEST['fb_sig_user'];
        try
        {
            return $facebook->api_client->photos_getAlbums($uid,null);
        }
        catch (FacebookRestClientException $ex)

        {
            return array();
        }
    }`

/**
   * get_photos()
   *
   * @param bool $bool_pids
   * @param mixed $aids (array of album ids or null)
   * @return array
   */
    function get_photos($bool_pids=true, $aids=null, $pids=null)
    {
        try
        {
            $p = $facebook->api_client->photos_get(null, $aids, $pids);
        }
        catch (FacebookRestClientException $ex)
        {
        }

```
    if ($bool_pids)
    {
        $pids = array();
        if (!empty($p))
        foreach($p as $p0)
            $pids[] = $p0['pid'];
        return $pids;
    }
    else
        return $p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I did it they logged in on my behalf (I put in my user/password) and navigated photo albums by expected HTML.

There were some legal things I had to "accept" and was notified of what they would do with my details.

Answer (score 0):

Click this below link and go through my comment. Perhaps it will help someone :)

[How to import photos from facebook into a website using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429100/how-to-import-photos-from-facebook-into-a-website-using-php)