# How to import photos from facebook into a website using php?

Tags: php, facebook

I am creating a site where a user that logs in with their Facebook account will see their pictures on the page . What code do i have to put in my website to see the loged in users pictures diplayed.

If someone can help me with a link to a tutorial or point me in the right direction.

I have read a lot of documentation from Facebook and on stack overflow but i cant find an answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this two ways: on the server-side (in PHP in your case) or on the client-side with the JavaScript SDK.

Both assume you have the required access credentials. You need to sign up for an application account to get these at the [Facebook Developer site](http://developers.facebook.com/)

### Server-Side

First-step is to get your application to participate in the OAuth authentication process. This is well-documented for PHP in the [Facebook guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) (see the Server-Side Flow section).

Once you've done that, you'll have an access token that you can call into the Graph API with. The endpoint to get the user's photos is `https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=<token>`. In this case the `me`, is always the user who signed in to give your application the token.

In PHP, assuming you've stored the access token in `$SESSION['token']` you can make a request for the photos payload with:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=" . $SESSION['token'];
$photos = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

The `$photos` object will be a list of `Photo` entities that are described in the [Facebook docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/).

### Client-Side

You'll need to setup the JavaScript SDK on your web pages as documented [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

Authentication on the client-side is handled by JavaScript SDK, again documented in the [authentication guide](http://developers.facebook.com/).

Using the SDK, you can make a client-side JavaScript call to the Graph API for the same photos structure:

```
FB.api('/me/photos', function(response) {
    if(!response || response.error) {
        // render error
    } else {
        // render photos
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering in a very understandable and clear way

Answer (score 0):

Check this other question on stack [How to import photos from Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297629/how-to-import-photos-from-facebook)

Answer (score 0):

I think Now Facebook has changed the way to import photos and so we have to first get albums and than to import photos of that album. At-least i made it in this way. :) Below are the basic api call using PHP

get albums :- `<?php $user_albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums', $params); ?>`
get album photos :- `<?php $user_album_photos = $facebook->api('/' . $album_id . '/photos', $params); ?>`

Now here is a full code summary. Do copy this code in file and check for doing import photos

```
<?php
include 'facebook/facebook.php';
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = YOUR_APP_ID;
$config['secret'] = YOUR_APP_SECRET;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
?>
<?php
if ($user_id && $access_token) {

    // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
    // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
    try {

        $params = array(
            'method' => 'get',
            'access_token' => $access_token
        );

        if (isset($_GET['aid']) && $_GET['aid'] != '') {
            $aid = $_GET['aid'];
            $user_album_photos = $facebook->api('/' . $aid . '/photos', $params);
            //echo "Photos<br/>"; 
            ?>

            <?php foreach ($user_album_photos['data'] as $key => $value) {
                ?>
                <div class="album">
                    <div class="frame photo_frame">
                        <div class="edit-photo-nohover" style="display:block">
                            <div><input type="checkbox" id="fbimport_id<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" value="<?= $value['id'] . ',' . $value['images']['0']['source'] . ',' . $value['name'] ?>" name="fbimport[]" > <span>Import this Memory</span></div>

                        </div>
                        <table class="test">
                            <tr><td>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="<?= $value['images']['0']['source'] ?>" height="100" width="100" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <h3 id='bottomcaption'><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3>
                    </div><br/>
                </div>
                <?php }
            ?>


        <?php
        } else {
            $user_albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums', $params);
            echo '<h3 class="page-title">Select Your Facebook Album</h3><br/><br/>';
            foreach ($user_albums['data'] as $key => $value) {

                /* load album if not blank */
                if (isset($value['count']) && $value['count'] != '' && $value['count'] != NULL && $value['count'] > 0) {

                    /* check if album has a cover photo. if not than load a default image */
                    if (isset($value['cover_photo']) && $value['cover_photo'] != '' && $value['cover_photo'] != NULL) {
                        $user_album_cover = $facebook->api('/' . $value['cover_photo'], $params);
                        $album_thumbnail = $user_album_cover['images']['0']['source'];
                    } else {
                        $album_thumbnail = 'default_thumb.gif';
                    }
                    /* check if album has cover photo end */
                    ?>
                    <div class="album">
                        <div class="frame photo_frame">
                            <table class="test">
                                <tr><td>
                                        <a href="?aid=<?= $value['id'] ?>" ><img src="<?= $album_thumbnail ?>" height="100" width="100" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <h3 id='bottomcaption'><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3>
                        </div><br/>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                }//if(isset($value['count']) && $value['count'] != '' && $value['count'] != NULL && $value['count']>0)
                /* load album if not blank end */
            }
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
} else {

    // No user, print a link for the user to login
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
}
?>
```