# undefined response , facebook javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to import some Photos from a Facebook page that I own.

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429100/how-to-import-photos-from-facebook-into-a-website-using-php) answer on Stack Overflow, more specifically the **Client-Side** part.

In the answer 3 steps are suggested.

1. Add the javascript SDK , which i do.
2. Something about Authentication but the link is wrong...
3. A piece of code for rendering the photos.

I skipped the 2nd step , cause I am not sure what to do there and I implemented the code in 3rd step :

```
FB.api('593959083958735/photos', function(response) {
                if(!response || response.error) {
                    // render error
                    alert("Noo!!");
                } else {
                    // render photos
                    alert("Yeah! " + response.status);
}
```

From here I get the alert `"Yeah! undefined"`. The response is always `undefined`. I think maybe because I should have done something in the authentication part.

All I am trying to do here , is to import some photos from a public Facebook page. Is this the correct way to do that? If yes why would I need any authentication for it. And what exactly should I do in the authentication part?

Comment: Change `response.status` to `response.data[0].source`

Comment: Then whats the need of the above code that the answerer gave? I mean the response is undefined , the response.error is undefined. Is there a reason to use the code above?

Comment: `response` is not undefined, it doesn't has any field with name `status`

Comment: When i alert response.alert is "undefined" . What are the attributes that response has in this case? I would like to query the page based on the album name and then get the photos of every album etc.

Comment: I noticed that 593959083958735/photos fetches me only the profile picture and not all the photos from all the albums. How do i tackle the problem here? Do i first call 593959083958735/albums , which fetches me all the ids of the albums , save them in an array , then FB.api('id-of-album/photos', function(response) {...} and get all the photos from every album? Is there a faster way to get the photos from a specific album , or to get all the photos from all the albums instead of doing this 2-step move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From here I get the alert "Yeah! undefined". The response is always undefined. I think maybe because I should have done something in the authentication part.

You are querying the photos from a page, so there *is no* `status` field in the response.

> All I am trying to do here , is to import some photos from a public Facebook page. Is this the correct way to do that? If yes why would I need any authentication for it.

You don’t need authentication for that – as you can see [here in the Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=593959083958735/photos), you get results even without an access token (after clearing the field). And you can see the structure of the response there as well.

Comment: Yes i ve seen the Graph API Explorer and the results. Thats exactly what i would like to do so that i can get the links from the photos of various albums and then show them to the user. So is there a need to use the fb SDK ? How can i see , how i can write the GET command with js ?

Comment: Using the SDK makes it easier …

Comment: Could you provide the code for making these queries that the Graph Api Explorer does? Or actually the response.data attribute that was mentioned in the comment above has everything i need to "play" with?

Comment: `console.log(response)` in your callback function – and then look into your browser’s JS console. there you can inspect the object and its structure easily.

Comment: To retrieve data it is suggested that you use the the Facebook's API. You may choose whatever means to access the API, either through SDK or by calling endpoints with required values. As far as code is concerned, everything is correct except change `response.status` to `response.data[i].source` within loop, to loop about the result.

Comment: Thank you both of you for your last 2 comments. Helped me a lot understand what was going on here. I can see that trough the response and the attributes of the response , i can query albums , photos , links everything. That is exactly what i needed.

Comment: @JonhSmid It would also be nice if you could close the question by accepting the answer if that helped you